# Where can I find resources which would explain the use/meaning of xaml like of datagrid and of datagrid of devexpress?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, devexpress

Like `dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate` or datagrid of Silverlight.

I cannot find a proper resource which would explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not provide a documentation related to your question.  However, below you will find some links which I hope will be of some help to you:

[Styles and Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5238)

[How to embed the ChartControl into the GridControl cell](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E2234)

[ComboBoxEdit - How to provide a different set of items for different data rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E2755)

[How to embed animation into grid cells](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E1532)

Comment: thank u, can u please provide help on this question, i cannot understand what am i doing wrong,,..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498765/textbox-not-displaying-the-binding-value-of-gridcontrol-why

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498765/textbox-only-displays-content-when-the-row-is-in-edit-mode-help-me-correct-this