# Textbox only displays content when the row is in edit mode

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have done every thing I can think of, but the textbox just does not display the values.

Where is my mistake?

```
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="secUserName" Header="TRAIL">

                                        <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data.secUserName, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>

                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
```

### and in vb

```
'<!-- load the datagrid -->
        Module1._Context.Load(Module1._Context.GetGESECsQuery())
        GridControl1.AutoPopulateColumns = False
        GridControl1.DataSource = Module1._Context.GESECs
```

Comment: This question is probably rather too localised, and in any case does not seem to have a solution posted after seven years. I think it can be closed as "unclear" or "too broad".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use our TextEdit instead of the standard TextBox:

```
<dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.secUserName}"></TextEdit>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
```

If this does not help, please remove the template and make certain that the grid has a column bound to the secUserName field and it shows data in runtime.

Comment: Path=DataContext.secUserName, here the datacontext will be replaced by the name of the domainservice object? like i have done "Public _Context As New DomainService1" so i replace by _Context.

Comment: sir, the above is not working, and yes i made certained it does show data at runtime, with only simple column binding.

Comment: this is the message i managed to get in the textedit box., "DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit" when clicked on it, works fine in edit mode

Comment: i have debugged the problem to the best of my beginners ability, but i cannot solve it, heres a link to my results, please help i will be very greatful, as i have my complete project using devx controls, and would have to switch back to silverlight simple controls if this adding controls to the gridcontrol and binding them to data "as done with simple silverlight grid very very easily"..

Comment: the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510675/the-vs10-debugger-say-it-cannot-find-the-datasource-column-in-silverlight-applica