# The VS10 debugger says it cannot find the datasource column in Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, devexpress, gridcontrol

### The error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'secUserName' property not found on 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.EditGridCellData' 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.EditGridCellData' (HashCode=2852273). BindingExpression: Path='secUserName' DataItem='DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.EditGridCellData' (HashCode=2852273); target element is 'DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit' (Name=''); target property is 'EditValue' (type 'System.Object')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'secUserName' property not found on 'DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit' 'DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit' (HashCode=19675928). BindingExpression: Path='secUserName' DataItem='DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.EditGridCellData' (HashCode=2852273); target element is 'DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit' (Name=''); target property is 'EditValue' (type 'System.Object')..
```

### The vb.net

```
Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Title = ApplicationStrings.HomePageTitle

        '<!-- load the datagrid -->
        Module1._Context.Load(Module1._Context.GetGESECsQuery())
        GridControl1.DataSource = Module1._Context.GESECs
        GridControl1.DataContext = Module1._Context.GESECs

    End Sub
```

### The XAML

```
 <dxg:GridColumn Header="TRAIL" FieldName="secUserName" >
 <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
 <ControlTemplate>
 <StackPanel>
 <dxe:TextEdit  EditValue="{Binding  Path=secUserName}"></dxe:TextEdit>
 </StackPanel>
 </ControlTemplate>
 </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
 </dxg:GridColumn>
```

### Problem

When the edittext is clicked (there by bringing the row in edit mode {with the pencil diagram on its side}) the content of the SECUSERNAME is displayed

But in the normal condition of just displaying the records, the textedit does not display anything.

Yes, the debugger show that the secusername is not valid, but why? What should I do to make this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change your binding code as follows:

```
"{Binding Path= DisplayText, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: yes, but now new problem. when i click on any other cell of any row, the texteditbox of that row doesnot display the content, it appears to be empty. Sir i am sure "devexpress" must be having a way for this, it may be complicated or too complex, but its a necessity of my project, i would be greatful if u can guide me to any resource available regarding what i am trying to achieve, i shall document all my efforts and post them so others are also helped.. thanku

Comment: hi, please check this question, have degugged, have studied devx online documentation, and but cannot solve the strange behaviour of textedit control from devexpress please help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565352/textedit-control-of-devexpress-loosing-focus-in-gridcontrol-and-losing-text-also